# How to check if any error has been added to a record?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have created a method which is being called through a trigger. I am adding error to a record if it is a duplicate one using 'addError()' method .

Now , I want to cover this method in my test class. How Can I check that on which records , error has been added ?

Comment: You could wrap your dml in a try-catch and assert the error message in the catch block.

Answer (score 20):

The [addError methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) in a Visualforce context will also add to the Apex Page messages collection, which you can access via the [ApexPages.getMessages method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_methods_system_apexpages.htm).

> When used in Visualforce controllers, the generated message is added to the collection of errors for the page.

```
    Test__c testRecord = new Test__c();
    testRecord.addError('Some error');
    testRecord.A_Number__c.addError('Field error');
    for(ApexPages.Message message : ApexPages.getMessages())
        System.debug(message.getComponentLabel() + ' : ' + message.getSummary());
```

The following results in...

> 20:03:00:155 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|null : Some error
>
> 20:03:00:156 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|A Number : Field error

Unfortunatly the record that generated the error is not availble.

Finally you might also be interested in the ApexPages.hasMessages method as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note: ApexPages.getMessages() works in VisualForce pages only, in case that is not clear.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Database.insert(), Database.update(), etc.. 
Then it will return a Database.SaveResult and if it have errors you can get them like this:

```
Database.SaveResult [] updateResult = Database.update(records, false);  
for (Database.SaveResult r : updateResult){  
  if (!r.isSuccess()){  
    for (Database.Error e : r.getErrors()){  
      // errors here  
    }   
  }  
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I want to check error without record insertion.

Comment: You can only get the errors after you insert/update/delete/upsert, as far as I know.